# PSUtil and Wine: Trying to get time a process ends, but Wine processes never terminate (just go to sleep)?

Tags: python, linux, wine, psutil

I am using Python's PSUtil library to **detect the exact time a given process completes**. Currently I do this by looking for when the process terminates, for which the following suite of tests works well on both **Windows** and **regular Linux** programs:

```
# Run a command and keep a reference
if do_run_command:
    process = psutil.Popen(command)
# Latch onto running process by PID
else:
    process = psutil.Process(int(pid))

# Loop until the process ends
while True:
    if not process.is_running():
        break

    if process.status() == psutil.STATUS_ZOMBIE:
        break

    try:
        # Command that gets information about the process

    except psutil.NoSuchProcess:
        break

# Store end time
```

However, when I try to use this on a program being run under **Wine**, none of those tests ever triggers. This is because **it appears Wine processes never actually terminate, but rather go to sleep indefinitely.** That includes the program running in Wine, the script that launches the program in Wine, etc. etc.

This is causing problems both in being able to detect when the programs truly end, and because the processes build up in memory until I eventually have to kill them manually.

-=-=-=-=-

I am running on **CentOS 6.0**. The main questions I have boil down to these:

1. Is there some sort of configuration that can be set for **Wine** to have
   it close the processes when complete? (I am rather new to Wine, and searching for this has proved maddeningly difficult)
2. Alternatively, is there another **PSUtil** test I could add to my Python script to get it to detect when these Wine processes are finishing (even if they are sleeping indefinitely)?